# How to switch between wi-fi networks at runtime (programmatically) in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, wifi

Is it possible to switch between WiFi networks in an iPhone App programmatically? At time of app execution if one network goes down but that is still connected and I want to switch to another wi-fi network. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions if you're brave, it's a list of undocumented (and probably-get-thrown-out-of-the-appstore-if-you-use) private APIs that relate to WiFi scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no iOS API for this, but there can be some possible solutions, like make it available on Cydia for jailbroken devices. AirServer just did this.

Answer (score 3):

Your iPhone app shouldn't manage wifi networks.  If it does, it won't get approved by Apple to be put in the App Store.  The iPhone itself manages wifi connections, not a third-party app.

Comment: is there any third party api present for that?

Comment: @Coder you cannot manage the WiFi networks. The user manages them herself. There is no API for this, third-party or otherwise.

Comment: @Jason - means there is no way for this, i am not interested in posting app on app store?

Comment: @coder if you're not interested in the app store then you should see the comment by Joachim. There are some private API you can use.

Comment: @JasonCoco yeah...i will try to check that and try to implement the same.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for  a jailbroken iphone, you can develop a MobileSubstrate extension/ Tweak with [Theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started) and hook into the SpringBoard Application. The SBWiFiManager interface is part of SpringBoard app and has a lot of useful methods that should help you with controlling WiFi.